# Ubuntu 12.04 serial port configuration with super IO chip SCH3114

Tags: ubuntu, serial-port, uart, upstart

I am trying to configure my UART ports during boot of ubuntu 12.04 server edition, somehow something else during boot is messing with the uart port configuration as well.

The details:

1. MSC SCH3114 super IO with 4 UARTs
2. Ubuntu 12.04 server
3. setserial installed but all startup scripts disabled
4. BIOS configured to enable all ports. Configures IO ports @ 0x03e8,
   0x03ef, 0x02e8 and 0x02ef
5. a getty is configured using upstart on ttyS2
6. I want to configure the ports correctly before starting this getty

The goal is to reconfigure the ports 0x02e8/0x02ef to 0x04e8/0x04ef during boot using upstart just before starting the getty in /etc/init/ttyS2.config. This is needed because the superIO chip needs to be reconfigured for correct operation. A user space program is available which configures the ports by a simple call: ./sioca -q << EOF << logdev concom (simplified semantics).

The problem:
I only accomplice my goal so far by having /etc/init/ttyS2.conf similar to:

```
start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL:[2345]
...
pre-start script
    sleep 5;
    *here is the user space sioca tool call to configure the super IO hardware (to set the correct IO port and interrupt (0x04** to IRQ 3, 0x03* to IRQ 4)
    *here are my setserial commands to tell the kernel where to find each UART
end script
...
*here is the actual /sbin/getty ttyS2 start*
```

I was hoping there was some event I could start on, such as "start on tty-device-added DEVNAME=*ttyS2", but this does not seem to work. The above example also really needs to contain the 'sleep 5', otherwise my ports are not configured correctly (either ports are suddenly busy and can't be configured, or ports are still set to 0x02e*). I have no idea why I need the sleep.

During boot I do see pnp related logging in the syslog and it is telling me the ports are set to 0x02e*. Can someone explain me what is happening here and how I reliably configure these ports? Are some drivers executing some initialization at the same time causing the messed up port configuration?

So in summary:

1. I need to reconfigure the ports before the getty on ttyS2 is started
   (otherwise the port is in use)
2. I need to call a user space program before configuring the ports to
   configure the superIO chip
3. The user space program outputs port IO locations and interrupt numbers which I have to use with setserial to configure the port
4. I can't figure out what is messing with the uart configure as well, why I would need to sleep 5 seconds to make the example upstart script work and most importantly how I can reliably configure the ports knowing that no other driver/startup script will undo my proper configuration

I hope I have gathered enough information for my question to be clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: *"here are my setserial commands to reconfigure each UART"* -- setserial is not doing what you think.  From the man page: *It is important to note that setserial merely tells the Linux kernel where it should expect to find the I/O port and IRQ lines of a particular serial port. It does -not- configure the hardware,*

Comment: Sorry i was a bit unclear, i am also calling the sioca tool inside the pre script which configures the hardware. I do this just before the setserial calls